# What's the correct use of free with returned pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, return-value

I have wrote a small example problem to learn about memory allocation and freeing this memory (to protect from memory leaks):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

long* foo(char str[]) {
    long *nums;
    nums = calloc(2,sizeof(long));

    //something is happening depending on what's inside the char[]

    nums[0] = 57347534;
    nums[1] = 84757;

    return nums;
}

int main() {
    char str1[400] = "This is a test";

    long* retValue = foo(str1);

    //some lines of checking content of "retValue"

    char str2[400] = "This is another test";

    retValue = foo(str2);

    //some more lines of checking content of "retValue"

    char str3[400] = "This is a final test";

    retValue = foo(str3);

    //again some more lines of checking content of "retValue"

    free(retValue);
}
```

So in my `main` function, I am using three char arrays which I will pass to my function. This function has a num pointer of long values where am `calloc`ing two of them. Then I am just calculating some numbers according to the content in `str[]` and return `nums`.

My questions about this are:

1. How do I free the memory I used for `nums`? Because I cannot free it before I use it for return.
2. Is it right to free the `retValue` in the last line there?
3. Am I right that I do not need to free my char arrays, because they are not dynamic?

Thanks for your answers, that would help me more safely use pointers!

Comment: The rule is *very* simple. Anything you `malloc` (`calloc` or whatever) you have to `free`. Somewhere. Once. Nothing else should be `free`d (well, some exclusions apply to pointers returned by certain memory allocating functions such as `strdup`),

Comment: And a good rule is : « whoever allocates calls free » otherwise you’re soon stuck in a mess

Comment: the posted code contains two memory leaks.  I.E. each time, before calling `foo()` again, need to call `free( retValue );`

Answer (score 9):

You need to call `free` before every new assignment to `retValue` (if the previous assignment came from `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`). Otherwise you will have memory leaks.

Every allocation must be matched by a `free`, plain and simple.

Comment: Thanks. So you think, if I am going to write free(retValue) before retValue = foo(str2); and retValue = foo(str3); then my program example provided is memory leak free?

Comment: And there will not by any free statement in the foo function, because I use the pointers in main?

Comment: @FranzFerdinand With your current code as shown, yes and yes.

Answer (score 3):

A good way to answer questions about memory allocation and use is to use a memory checker - I'll use Valgrind:

```
gcc-8 -std=c11 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds         50627661.c    -o 5062766

50627661.c: In function ‘foo’:
50627661.c:3:16: warning: unused parameter ‘str’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 long* foo(char str[]) {
           ~~~~~^~~~~
```

```
valgrind -q --leak-check=full ./50627661   

==14785== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14785==     in use at exit: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
==14785==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 48 bytes allocated
==14785== 
==14785== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==14785==    at 0x4C2EBA5: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14785==    by 0x10867F: foo (50627661.c:5)
==14785==    by 0x1086F6: main (50627661.c:18)
==14785== 
==14785== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==14785==    at 0x4C2EBA5: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14785==    by 0x10867F: foo (50627661.c:5)
==14785==    by 0x108758: main (50627661.c:24)
```

This shows that of the three allocations we made, we only freed one of them - the other two leaked.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to clutter your calling code with `free`, the alternative is to pass to the callee an array mangaged by the caller:

```
long foo(char str[], long *nums, int size) {
    if (size < 2) {  // passed array must be at least 2 long
        return -1;
    }

    //something is happening depending on whats inside the char[]

    nums[0] = 57347534;
    nums[1] = 84757;

    return 2;   // returns used size (or -1 for error)
}

int main() {
    long retValue[2];
    char str1[400] = "This is a test";

    if (-1 == foo(str1, retValue, 2)) {
        // process error condition
    }

    //some lines of checking content of "retValue"

    char str2[400] = "This is another test";

    if (-1 == foo(str2, retValue, 2)) {
        // process error condition
    }

    //some more lines of checking content of "retValue"

    char str3[400] = "This is a final test";

    if (-1 == foo(str3, retValue, 2)) {
        // process error condition
    }

    //again some more lines of checking content of "retValue"

    //free(retValue);  no need for free since nothing was allocated...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey, that is an interesting idea as well, thanks for your answer.